# Embedding a shell command in applescript not working - how do I support names with spaces?

Tags: shell, applescript

I can't get this to work. I need to rename all of the .CR2 files to *.cr2 in the chosen directory. I need this to work on files with a space in the filename too.

```
set varChosenfolder to POSIX path of (choose folder)
(do shell script "for file in " & varChosenfolder & "*.CR2; do mv '$file' '`basename '$file' .CR2`.cr2'; done")
```

I want to do this with a shell script and not be the tell command to "Finder", as I find shell scripts to work much faster.

EDIT:
I somehow managed to put something together, although I'm not sure this is the optimal method. I started out using 'ls', however I had difficulties making that work with foldernames and filenames with spaces in the names.
So I ended up with this:

```
on fixextensions()
try

set varFilestorename to (do shell script "find " & varChosenfolder & " -type f -depth 1 | grep '.CR2'")


    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {return}
    set varOldfilenames to paragraphs of varFilestorename as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""


    repeat with i in paragraphs of varOldfilenames
        set varSinglenewfilename to ((text 1 thru -4 of i) & "cr2")
        (do shell script "mv " & "\"" & i & "\"" & space & "\"" & varSinglenewfilename & "\"")
    end repeat
on error
    #       display dialog "No CR2 files with capital letters"
end try
end fixextensions
```

Comment: Try `do shell script "cd " & varChosenfolder & " && for file in *.CR2 ...."`

Comment: Thanks, man...
Somehow I managed to put something together that actually works! Althoug I don't know if it is the optimal method :-)

Comment: Using string concatenation to form scripts is major-security-bugs-level dangerous. Someone who could control the filename in the directory you're processing could run arbitrary commands. Just say no.

Comment: ...to give you an idea of what I'm talking about, consider the file created by `touch $'hello$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'.cr2'`.

Comment: ...your original code is much safer in that respect: it's only vulnerable to malicious directory names, not filenames.

Comment: As a rule, by the way -- file any answer you come up with yourself *as an answer*, not as an edit to the question. That way your question and your answer can be upvoted/downvoted/commented on/etc. separately, and you can mark your question answered if that answer you came up with works for you.

Comment: @Polle, ...if your answer-in-the-question is still there in a few days, I'll be reverting it from the question and adding it as a community-wiki answer (meaning nobody gains or loses rep from it). If you'd rather have it in your own name, so you can get rep from that answer should anyone upvote it, please take that same action yourself. See [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) for related discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is never to generate code by substituting dynamically-generated contents such as filenames. If it's necessary to do so, then one can avoid serious security bugs by using constructs that quote the content in question to ensure that it can't be malicious if parsed as code (and/or contain contents that cause it to escape its quoting and *be* parsed as code).

```
set varChosenfolder to POSIX path of (choose folder)
do shell script "for file in " & quoted form of varChosenfolder & "/*.CR2; do mv \"$file\" \"$(basename \"$file\" .CR2)\".cr2; done"
```

---

The actual command this runs differs only in whitespace (and the specifics of the path used at invocation) from the following:

```
sh -c '
  for file in /path/to\ your/folder/*.CR2; do
    mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .CR2)".cr2;
  done
'
```

Notably, this script:

- Only substitutes a value which AppleScript was told to ensure was safe with the `quoted form of` construct, but is otherwise entirely hardcoded.
- Has all expansions performed inside double quotes, including the expansion of the `basename` command's result; this prevents literals with whitespace or glob character from behaving undesirably.